# How to show only the formatted error in a npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-sass

I am creating several npm scripts, and I saw that in the case that one fails, an error object is returned. I would like to show in the console, only the formatted property of that object. Is that possible?

Currently I see in the console:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "stylesheets/main.scss",
  "line": 6,
  "column": 3,
  "message": "property \"adfasdagdajhgdaj\" must be followed by a ':'",
  "formatted": "Error: property \"adfasdagdajhgdaj\" must be followed by a ':'\n        on line 6 of assets/stylesheets/main.scss\n>>   adfasdagdajhgdaj\n   --^\n"
}
```

I would like to have only:

```
"Error: property \"adfasdagdajhgdaj\" must be followed by a ':'\n        on line 6 of assets/stylesheets/main.scss\n>>   adfasdagdajhgdaj\n   --^\n"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a try catch block and log only the formatted

```
try {
  //Do cool stuff
}catch (e) {
  console.log(e.formatted);
}
```

Comment: do you suggest to put a try { } catch () inside package.json?